# Relative keypress event to the handler event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a comments system inside a table.
Each row can contain comments and a textbox to add new ones. This options are created after clicking in the comments icon. (first event handler)

I am trying to allow posting comments by pressing enter (as well as by using a "save" button) but I am having a problem with the `keypress` event.

It is fired only for the first `click` event.

Here's a fiddle of my problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/imac/9mx7K/9/

As you can see, it fires only for the first `click` event. I would like it to fire only for the current selected/active input. Would it be possible?

I have also tried it adding the `keypress` event inside an input `click` event without success:
http://jsfiddle.net/imac/9mx7K/10/

Thanks.

Comment: First all your your click is fired correctly you initialize the variable within the click event so it looks like not firing. check this link http://jsfiddle.net/Dineshkani/9mx7K/11/

Comment: I think it is happening because $(document) is global scope. So when you create global scope function it focus all variables called cont...

Comment: $(this).keypress(function(e) {

Comment: @Steve Try using like this http://jsfiddle.net/Dineshkani/9mx7K/13/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just done an update, working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9mx7K/14/

```
$('.demo').on('click', function (e) {
$(this).next('input')
       .slideToggle()
       .data('cont', 0)
       .on('keydown', function (e) {
           $(this).data('cont', $(this).data('cont')+1);
           if (e.which == 13) {
                $(this).next('span')
                       .html('Active input ('+$(this).data('cont')+' enters)');
           }
       });
});
```

This keeps track of each individual input's count using `.data()`.

Comment: @DmitryKvochkin - thanks for pointing that out. I've updated my answer with a working version.

Comment: The counter was not a problem anyway. Thanks!! It was more simple than what i though :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input').click(function(){

       $('input').keypress(function(e) {
            cont++;
            //on enter
            if(e.which == 13) {
                $(this).next().html('Active input ('+cont + ' enters)');
            }

           // This only enables the first input
           e.unbind();
        });
    });
```

[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dineshkani/9mx7K/13/)